# Django: user.is_authenticated false after signup, allauth

Tags: django, django-allauth

I'm trying to set allauth up so that when a user successfully signs up they are redirected back to the page before they signed up and are automatically logged in.

I've got the redirect working using a custom account adapter. However they are not logged in. Strangely allauth does add "Successfully signed in as X" to messages. Checking `{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}` in the template returns false, same for `is_active`. I need to go and manually log in.

My settings for allauth are:

```
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = "username_email"
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = "optional"
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS = 'main.forms.SignupForm'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
ACCOUNT_PRESERVE_USERNAME_CASING = True
ACCOUNT_ADAPTER = 'main.adapters.MyAccountAdapter
```

adapters.py

```
class MyAccountAdapter(DefaultAccountAdapter):

    def get_login_redirect_url(self, request):
        path = request.POST.get('next', '/')
        return path.format(username=request.user.username)
```

`{{ request.user }}` returns `AnonymousUser`

forms.py

```
class SignupForm(forms.Form):
    password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    def signup(self, request, user):
        reviewer = Reviewer()
        reviewer.user = user
        reviewer.user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        reviewer.user.password = self.cleaned_data['password1']
        reviewer.user.username = self.cleaned_data['username']
        reviewer.save()


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SignupForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Debugging doesn't look like my custom account adapter is ever run, although the redirect still works as expected.

Ok figured out the redirect works as expected as I provide the 'next' field in my forms which allauth uses.

**Update**

Stepping through the code, looks like `request.user` goes through the allauth code fine, `is_authenticated` and `is_active` are both true. It gets passed to the Django middleware, it's still as expected and a response is created. Then I believe another redirect is occurring and by the time the `request` object hits the view for the page where the user signed up from `request.user` has been scrubbed and it's now an an `AnonymousUser`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems it was the `SignupForm` `def signup` where the issue lay. I removed the password fields and `self.cleaned_data` fields and it now works as expected. I honestly have no idea why this would prevent the auto sign-in but save the user model fine and not throw up any errors.